# Access base_url() Or site_url() in CodeIgniter's custom config file

Tags: codeigniter

I want to access`base_url()` method so that I can get my application url in custom config file.

I don't want to write `$config['base_url'] = 'some url';` in custom config file.

Comment: Try `$this->config->item('base_url')`.

Comment: This is not working

Comment: @MSaikat have added my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your question unclear but give it ago. To enable base_url load the [url helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#url-helper)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

$autoload['config'] = array('custom'); // application > config / custom.php
```

The create the custom config file

```
<?php

// Testing
echo config_item('base_url');

$config['test'] = '111';
```

Or on controller load in the [__construct](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors) area

Check [filenames and classes](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) starts with first letter only upper case

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
 }

}
```

> Make sure you have set your base url in CodeIgniter 3 and above
>   versions it is recommended.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Answer (score 0):

To use base_url(), you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done in `application/config/autoload.php`, then:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or manually:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

To print returned value:

```
echo base_url();
```

Comment: Loading url helper at autoload.php first. But while going to use base_url() at custom config file (config/my_config.php) throwing error i.e. undefined method base_url()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->config` array that contains all settings loaded by default.
For example: you can create `sample.php` config file and put next code into

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sample
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|
*/

//here you can see how is used base_url value from config.php
$config['r'] = $this->config['base_url'];
```

In controller you are calling it as any other config item:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->config->item('r'));
    }
}
```

Autoload `sample.php` in config section of `autoload.php` file or manage loading as appropriate for your application.